# Is the Möbius strip the first non-orientable surface discovered?

Tags: general-topology, math-history, surfaces

This is more of a historical question, but I would like to know if the notion of an non-orientable surface was known before Möbius and if so, if a surface bearing this characteristic had been indicated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: There are over 1700 questions at the present site under the tag [tag:math-history].

Comment: There is also a Meta question about accepting "history" question : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23531/are-questions-about-history-on-topic?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

The real projective plane arguably was known before the Mobius strip.  However, it was mostly studied as an entity in projective geometry, not topology.  The projective geometers who studied it may or may not have been aware of the special topological characteristic of $\mathbb R P^2$ having to do with orientability which may have been conceptualized considerably later than the projective plane itself.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer shows a lot of uncertainty about the particulars of history, so is it that we don't have any specific references to people addressing this problem?

Comment: Try to look up projective geometry at wiki.  *A lot* is  known about its history :-)

Comment: The notion of an abstract surface did not exist until early 20th century, only surfaces embedded in the 3-space were studied, although one can say that since Riemann there was a concept of an abstract surface, but quite imprecise one. In any case, Riemann surfaces (and Riemann's notion  of manifolds) came after Moebius. Accordigly, there was no notion of orientability/nonorientability of abstract surfaces.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, by this logic, there could have been no infinitesimals before Robinson, either :-)